# Animation with TranslateY is holding Constraints

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

Before you start:

- I'm using `Kotlin`
- I'm using `ConstraintLayout` (switching to `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` is not an option)

I have my `layout` as follows:

```
     <TextView android:id="@+id/myRefer" .../>
     <ScrollView
         ...
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/myRefer">
     ...
     </ScrollView>
```

And my animation is developed as follows:

```
        myRefer.animate()
            .translationY(-myRefer.height.toFloat())
            .alpha(0.0f)
```

So far so good, no problem with the `animation`, everything goes as expected.

The problem is, I thought that from the moment I'm using `TranslateY`, the `ScrollView` would follow the new position reference (topToBottom). But it keeps a white hole (as if my `TextView` is still using the reference height)

**Did I misunderstand the use of TranslateY, or am I using animate() incorrectly? How would I solve this problem for my ScrollView to follow the reference.**

Note: Don't suggest using `onAnimatonEnd` and setting `View.GONE`, it just makes things worse.

Answer (score -1):

I would just use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on the layout. And then instead of `animate...` just call `myRefer.visibility = View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`. It will have the same effect and the Scrollview will adjust to the hidden element.

Comment: Not the same effect after all. I will not have the TextView slideUp. And the Scrollview effect won't be organic (it's just repositioning).

Comment: It should slide up if you placed the animateLayoutChanges correctly. Where did you add animateLayoutChanges? It should be at the root layout where myRefer resigns.

Comment: The purpose of the question is not simply that ScrollView fills in the space, but rather follows TextView's translational motion (based on the applied constraints). Applying as you said I have only one show / hide of TextView, ie there is no organic movement in it.

Comment: Why don't you just apply the same translationY animation on scrollview then?